# Installed Foundation instead of Server Service Pack

Tags: 2013, upgrade, service-pack

I installed the wrong service pack 1 on my dev server and now PSConfig won't run. What is the best thing to do? I can't roll back so can I just proceed with installing the SharePoint Server Service Pack 1? KB2880552

Answer (score 1):

Install Server SP1 over the top. Run psconfig.

Comment: I downloaded the Server SP1, double clicked, and get an error immediately "The installation of this package failed"

Answer (score 0):

What error you are getting? Yes you cant rollBack the service pack.

As you said, You should Install the SharePoint Server Service pack and then runt he config wizard. Their will be no issue.

Comment: Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPManager.BootStrap(Guid sessionId, SPUpgradeOperationFlags flags)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeBootstrapTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

Comment: Getting the same error as this post and they suggest you can run a Repair from Control Panel
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c4662e67-369b-45a5-ac18-39be4729fccd/failed-to-call-gettypes-on-assembly-microsoftofficetranslationservices?forum=sharepointadmin